# ActiveRecord Table Aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, join

Does anyone know if it's somehow possible to setup an alias for an ActiveRecord table join?

Something like:

```
User.find(:all, :alias => "Users as u", :joins => "Friends as f", :select => "u.id,f.name")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but you need to include the 'ON' statement and the join statement if you overwrite the join.

```
User.find(:all, :joins => " as u INNER JOIN Friends as f ON f.user_id = u.id", :select => "u.id,f.name")
```

or in Rails 3+

```
User.joins("as u INNER JOIN Friends as f on f.user_id = u.id")
    .select("u.id, f.name")
    .all
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this a hack?

Comment: To an extent, yes it is. But generally when you start to override the assumed behavior, it is a hack. I believe there is some arel available now that would make this a little bit less hackish. But as far as I am aware, this is still the easiest way to do complex joins while maintaining the ORM functionality. Mind you, I haven't been doing a great deal of rails dev in the last year so I could have missed something in later releases.

Comment: A less hackish way to alias the main table would be to use the [from method](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/from) available in Rails 3+, e.g. `User.from("users as u").joins("INNER JOIN Friends as f on f.user_id = u.id").select("u.id, f.name")`